# Can 'something else' be used negatively?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

I've used the expression "to be something else" in a lot of different contexts. I'm wondering now whether sometimes I have used it wrongly.
This is when I have said it to refer to someone as a mess or a disaster. e.g.:

> A: "He lost his phone again".
> B: "Really? I can't believe it. He's something else".

Is the use of this expression correct to say such things? Can this phrase be used negatively?

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/something-else) says **something else**: unusual, especially extremely good or extremely bad.

Comment: Every compliment can work sarcastically and therefore negatively. You humble child, you. Sweets for the sweet. Classy. A god. Big help.

Answer (score 7):

*Something else* has a pretty broad scope: It can be used both positively or negatively, the only requirement is that it be referring to an extreme.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/something-else):

> unusual, esp. extremely good or extremely bad:

[TfD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/he%27s+something+else):

> 1. **To be hilarious and extremely entertaining.**
>    *Jack's story was something else, wasn't it? I thought I was going to cry, I was laughing so hard!*
> 2. **To be very remarkable or intriguing.**
>    *That performance was something else, Sarah. I've never seen anything like it!*
> 3. **To be abhorrent or repugnant.**
>    *I mean, we've all done things we're not proud of. But stealing money from your dying mother? That's something else, Marty.*

So, no, you're not wrong to use it as you did.